# can't add generic list to generic map

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic map

```
Map<String, List<A<?>>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

then I have a list like:

```
List<A<Integer>> list1 = getData();
List<A<String>> list2 = getData2();
```

I'm trying to add them to the map, but I'm getting an error saying the argument is wrong.

```
map.put("a", list1);
map.put("b", list2);
//doesn't work
```

Making the map like

```
Map<String, List<A>> map = HashMap<>();
```

doesn't work either.
How can I change "map" to be able to add those 2 lists?

Comment: Show your error

Answer (score 3):

Generics are not evaluated recursively.  The wildcard (`<?>`) does not get evaluated here.

If you have a `Map<String, List<A<?>>>` then you *must* add `List<A<?>>` values to it;  `List<A<Integer>>` does not qualify as a `List<A<?>>`.  `List<A<?>>` means a List of A instances with unknown types, so you must pass a List of A instances with unknown types.

What you can do is create such a List, explicitly, and add all the elements of your typed-A List to it:

```
List<A<Integer>> list1 = getData();
List<A<String>> list2 = getData2();

List<A<?>> list1Unknown = new ArrayList<>();
list1.forEach(list1Unknown::add);

List<A<?>> list2Unknown = new ArrayList<>();
list2.forEach(list2Unknown::add);

map.put("a", list1Unknown);
map.put("b", list2Unknown);
```

Comment: That explains so much. Would replacing `List<A<?>>` with just plain `List<A>` allow `List<A<Integer>>` to be passed in?

Comment: Yes it most certainly would. For a more general solution to the question, please see my answer below.

Comment: instead of `list1.forEach(list1Unknown::add)` just use `list1Unknown.addAll(list1)`

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes, because using a raw type in a statement causes the compiler to ignore all generics for that statement.

Comment: Could you not also just cast `List<A<Integer>>` into `List<A<?>>`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist The compiler doesn’t allow it.  Using a raw type causes it to ignore the rules, but in this case, the compiler pays attention to them.  Wildcard matching only goes one level deep, so even though `A<?>` is assignment compatible with `A<Integer>`, `List<A<?>>` is not assignment compatible with `List<A<Integer>>`.

Comment: @VGR. Thank you very much for that explanation. I've been wondering about this for a while, but never took the trouble to learn the underlying cause. One of life's great mysteries, solved!

Answer (score -2):

If you just want to place any two lists inside the map then use: `Map<String, List> map = new HashMap<>();`.

Alternatively, if you want to restrict the type of the List that you would like to add:

`Map<String, List<? extends Object>> map = new HashMap<>();`.

Why I have chosen to extend `Object` is because it is the only class present in the hierarchies of both `Integer` and `String`.

Comment: *the use of rawtypes is discouraged*

Comment: `List<?>` is actually shorthand for `List<? extends Object>`.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don’t think that that is strictly true. You cannot add items to List<?> but you can add any item to List<? extends Object>. With List<?>, you do not know the type of the objects in the list however with List<? extends Object>, you know that the list contains any object that extends Object.

Comment: You misunderstand generic wildcards.  `List<? extends Object>` does not mean “you may place any object in this LIst.”  It means “this List is restricted to an exact type, but the compiler does not know exactly what type.”  `List<? extends Object>` may, for example, refer to a List declared as `List<Number>`.