# Why can't a nested wildcard be assigned to a variable with a type parameter?

Tags: java, generics

Consider this example:

```
static class Generic<E> {}

static void run() {
    Generic<?> x = null;
    take(x);
}

static <E> void take(final Generic<E> x) {}
```

In `run`, the wildcard in the type of `x` represents some unknown type `T`. The `E` parameter of the `take` method can be assigned any type. The compiler infers that it's safe to assign `T` to `E`.

---

In the second example we nest the wildcard one level deeper:

```
static void run() {
    Generic<Generic<?>> x = null;
    take(x);
}

static <E> void take(final Generic<Generic<E>> x) {}
```

In this example the wildcard still represents some unknown type `T` and the `E` parameter can be assigned any type. Why does the compiler not infer that `T` can be assigned to `E` and allow this code to compile? Is there a principled reason for this code not compiling?

Note: changing the `take` method in the second example to the below compiles:

```
static <E> void take(final Generic<Generic<? extends E>> x) {}
```

Is there an essential difference between `Generic<Generic<E>>` and `Generic<Generic<? extends E>>` when `E` is unbounded?

Comment: A minor remark: since generics are invariant, you should use `<? extends E>` for your `take(...)`-method parameters (`final Generic<? extends E> x`) to comply with [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super).

Comment: @Turing85 I agree in real code but I'm asking a question about this specific code. Changing the type of `take`'s parameter in the second example to `Generic<Generic<? extends E>>` makes the compiler happy. But I would like to understand why.

Comment: This is the reason I wrote it as a remark ;) Actually, to really comply with PECS, you would write `Generic<? extends Generic<? extends E>>`. As to WHY it is that the compiler rejects this... I am not fully sure.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49685216/cant-add-generic-list-to-generic-map

Answer (score 4):

`Generic<Generic<?>>` does not mean `Generic<Generic<T>>` for an unknown `T`. It means the specific type `Generic<Generic<?>>`. An object of type `Generic<Generic<?>>` is never of type `Generic<Generic<T>>` for any `T`.

For example, if you had `List<List<?>>`, this would be a list that can take `List<String>`, `List<Integer>`, `List<Object>`, etc. as elements. There is no type `T` for which `List<List<T>>` can do that.

Intuitively, the first snippet calls `take<T>` for some unknown `T`, while the second snippet would need to specifically call `take<?>` with `?` as the type parameter, which is forbidden. Concretely, I believe Java generates a fresh type variable for the `?` on `Generic<?>` in [capture conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10) for the first snippet, which doesn't happen for the nested wildcard in the second snippet. I haven't fully figured out how the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-18.html) says the type inference plays out, though.

Comment: Clear and concise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think it is also for the Liskov principle. A generic type is a generic class or interface that is parameterized over types. The Liskov substitution principle doesn't work with the parameterized types. 
For example is a compile time error if you write:

```
List<Numbers> list = new ArrayList<Integers>();
```

The same applies to wildcards: when evaluating `Generic<Generic<E>>` with `Generic<Generic<?>>` the Liskov principle tells you that `Generic<E>` and `Generic<?>` have not a subtyping relationship. That's why it gives a compile time error, because it cannot infer nothing from ? with E.

Comment: I think the meat of the question is _why_ `Generic<E>` and `Generic<?>` have no subtyping relationship in light of the latter being assignable to the former.